# Is stippling polygons supported in DirectX?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx

Is stippling polygons supported in DirectX in some way? I am referring to this OpenGL method:

```
void glPolygonStipple(const GLubyte *mask);
```

> Defines the current stipple pattern for filled polygons. The argument
>   mask is a pointer to a 32 x 32 bitmap that's interpreted as a mask of
>   0s and 1s. Where a 1 appears, the corresponding pixel in the polygon
>   is drawn, and where a 0 appears, nothing is drawn. Figure 2-10 shows
>   how a stipple pattern is constructed from the characters in mask.
>   Polygon stippling is enabled and disabled by using glEnable() and
>   glDisable() with GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE as the argument. The
>   interpretation of the mask data is affected by the glPixelStore*()
>   GL_UNPACK* modes. (See "Controlling Pixel-Storage Modes" in Chapter
>   8.)

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can achieve the same result with shaders. Also you won't be limited by 32x32 mask.

Comment: Do you know any useful resource about this kind of Pixel Shader?

Comment: Literally any modern opengl or DirectX tutorial involves shaders.

Comment: I meant a ready to use pixel shader source code to obtain this kind of stippling...